# Proving that $3\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \trianglelefteq \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

I have to prove  that $$3\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \trianglelefteq \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}.$$

I proved $3\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \leq \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, so I have to show

$\forall A \in \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z},$ $A^{-1}+3\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}+A \subset 3\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$.

(Proof)

Let $A \in \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$.

I can write $A=a+6\mathbb{Z}$ where $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and then $A^{-1}=-a+6\mathbb{Z}$.

I'm stuck here.

What I have to do next is letting $B \in A^{-1}+3\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}+A $ and showing $B \in 3\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}.$

But when I let $B \in A^{-1}+3\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}+A $, how can I express $B$ ?

Comment: If $G$ is an *abelian* group and $H \leq G$, then $H \trianglelefteq G$. Proof: Take $h \in H$. Then for any $g \in G$ we have $g^{-1}hg = g^{-1}gh = h \in H$. Since $h$ was arbitrary, it follows that $g^{-1}Hg \subseteq H$ for any $g \in G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $G:=\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ is abelian, each of its subgroups is normal. (See @azif00's excellent comment.)

---

[Every quotient of an abelian group is abelian.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Quotient_Group_of_Abelian_Group_is_Abelian) But $\Bbb Z$ is abelian, so $6\Bbb Z$ is normal in $\Bbb Z$, so $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ is abelian.

---

It suffices, then, to show that $H:=3\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z\le G$.

I will use the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test#:%7E:text=In%20abstract%20algebra%2C%20the%20one,is%20also%20in%20the%20subset.)

Since $0\times 3=0\times 6=0$, we have $0+6\Bbb Z\in H$. Hence $H\neq\varnothing$.

Suppose $a+6\Bbb Z\in H$. Then $a\in 3\Bbb Z$. But $3\Bbb Z\subseteq \Bbb Z$. Hence $a+6\Bbb Z\in G$. Hence $H\subseteq G$.

Suppose $x=a+6\Bbb Z, y=b+6\Bbb Z\in H$, for some $a,b\in 3\Bbb Z$. Then

$$\begin{align}
x-y&= (a+6\Bbb Z)-(b+6\Bbb Z)\\
&=(a+6\Bbb Z)+((-b)+6\Bbb Z)\\
&=(a+(-b))+6\Bbb Z\\
&=(a-b)+6\Bbb Z,
\end{align}$$

but $a-b\in 3\Bbb Z$ since $3\Bbb Z\le \Bbb Z$. Hence $x-y\in H$.

Hence $H\le G$.

Hence $H\unlhd G$.

Comment: If this answers your question, @Luca, please don't forget to accept it; and if not, what is the first thing that doesn't make sense to you?