# Why is $S_3 / A_3$ cyclic group of order $2$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups, quotient-group

Consider symmetric group $S_3$ and alternating group $A_3$.

I wonder why quotient group $S_3 / A_3$ is cyclic group of order $2$.

I know $S_3 / A_3=\{ \sigma \circ A_3 \mid \sigma \in S_3 \}$ but I don't know why this is cyclic group of order $2$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you know why it has order $2$? Or why the set has $2$ elements.

Comment: By definition of the alternating group as kernel of the signum, $|S_n/A_n|=2$ for $n\ge 3$. Every group $G$ of prime order is cyclic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $A_3\le S_3$ and their orders are $3!/2$ and $3!$, respectively; more specifically,

$$|S_3|=[S_3:A_3]|A_3|,$$

while $[S_3:A_3]=|S_3/A_3|.$

Also, the only group of order two is $\Bbb Z_2$ up to isomorphism, so it must be cyclic.

Comment: What is "$\mathbb{Z}_2$" ?

Comment: The two element group $\mathbb Z_2 = \{0,1\}$. It is easy to check that it is a cyclic group under addition. $\mathbb Z_2$ is the only group with two elements (to check, try constructing another two element group – after adding the necessary identity element, the only other element must behave like 1 in $\mathbb Z_2$)

Comment: It stands for the group $(\{[0]_2, [1]_2 \}, +_2)$, where $$[a]_2=\{b\in \Bbb Z:2\mid a-b\}$$ and $$[x]_2+_2[y]_2=[x+y]_2,$$ @Luca.

Comment: Does this answer your question, @Luca? Please don't forget to accept the answer if so; and if not, what's the first thing that doesn't make sense?

Comment: @Shaun Soryy, I've forgotten to accepct.

Comment: No worries, @Luca; thank you for accepting. Please don't forget [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4185245/104041) while you're at it.